# Configure ROSTest + Hudson for individual bug reports?

Tags: ros, rostest, unit-testing

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey gang,

Since I notice that Willow Garage is using Hudson for managing their build process, I was hoping somebody could help me understand if there's a way to set up my own Hudson (which I've done) and config it and ROSTest to generate individual bug reports, rather than the 1 big build + test report.

As I currently have things, my hudson server is performing a clean checkout of my ROS project every night, then invoking a small script which sets up the paths, performs the "rosmake" (which puts out a bunch of output on the console) and then I have it trigger the "make test" in each package/stack that we're working on to run the unit tests. If ANY of these fail, it produces a single master roll-up error report that Hudson posts to our bug tracking system.

What I'd really prefer to do is have each unit test generate it's own bug report if there is a problem (we're using Collabnet's Teamforge system and the Hudson Collabnet plugin.)

Is there a way to set things up to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42381/configure-rostest-+-hudson-for-individual-bug-reports?/) by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tests in ros produce standard junit xml output.  You can parse them anyway you want and send triggers however you want as well.  That's more of a Jenkins type issue.  I suggest you contact the Jenkins forums.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-10-10**:
In case you find a solution, please post it here as well! I would be interested, too! :-)